# Why does a std::getline call on std::cin not wait for user input?

Tags: c++, user-input, iostream, cin, getline

Is there any good reason why:

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

the getline call won't wait for user input? Is the state of cin messed up somehow?

Comment: post your code, to get an answer which solves your problem rather than speculative answers.

Comment: Is there a `'\n'` sitting in the input buffer from before, perhaps?

Comment: Of course there's a good reason why it's happening - you've messed up somehow :-) Post more code that demonstrates the problem (as others have mentioned).

Comment: The `cin` is allowed to be buffered.  Many implementations require a *newline* in order to *flush* the input buffer and return the data to the calling program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely you are trying to read a string after reading some other data, say an `int`.

consider the input:

```
11
is a prime
```

if you use the following code:

```
std::cin>>number;
std::getline(std::cin,input)
```

the `getline` will only read the newline after 11 and hence you will get the impression that it's not waiting for user input.

The way to resolve this is to use a dummy `getline` to consume the new line after the number.

Comment: A better way to resolve this, is to always use `std::getline` for reading any input, and never use `std::cin >> ` style input. For reading an int, you can read the line in a string buffer, and then parse that buffer to get the int out of it (using `std::stringstream` eg.).

Comment: An alternative way to get rid of the extra '\n' rather than a dummy getline call would be something like `cin.ignore(1, '\n');`.

Comment: Are you guys discussing a problem, which is probably **NOT** what the OP is facing? Unless the OP posts a source code, All speculations are futile.

Comment: @Als: it's called psychic debugging, i.e. having seen a problem before and therefore knowing its probable cause. :) Sure, it might be something else, but there's no harm in trying to answer based on available info and one's own experience.

Comment: Bingo! Mr. Hafiz, your ESP powers are terrifying. Thanks!

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee this *is* what the OP is facing.  I've seen this problem hundreds of times, and it has *always* been because of a call to `operator>>` preceding a call to `getline`, leaving a '\n' in the input buffer.

Comment: @Sven: Thanks very much. Reading command-line inputs isn't something I have done much. So I ran into some basic newbie issues. Thanks for sorting it out.

Comment: @Sven: All the best with your psychic debugging. I will stick to answering a Q only knowing enough information to answer a Q.

Comment: This problem bit me very hard. Thankfully the dummy call to getline() came to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following code and it worked ok.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string  input;
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << "You input is: " << input << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I guess in your program that you might already have something in you input buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This code does not work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
int nr;
std::cout << "Number: ";
std::cin >> nr;

std::string  input;
std::cout << "Write something: ";
getline(std::cin, input);
std::cout << "You input is: " << input << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

This *does* work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
int nr;
std::cout << "Number: ";
std::cin >> nr;

std::string x;
std::getline(std::cin,x);

std::string  input;
std::cout << "Write something: ";
getline(std::cin, input);
std::cout << "You input is: " << input << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to authoritative sources (in particular, my opinion ), this is an acceptable way to solve this well-known issue.

Answer (score 0):

this occurred cause before std::getline(std::cin, input); there's newline char (/n). The getline reads until it encounters /n. Therefore it will read an empty string and return null without waiting for the users input.

To counter this we use an dummy getline, or cin.ignore(1, /n);