# Dynamic parametrized constructor issue in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, parameterized

I am here including a simple program that written in C++ where I am trying to use a parametrized constructor. My idea is to instantiate the class dynamically and capture the required task. 
But whenever I run the program and enter the task 1 it simply prints the two lines (i.e. Enter Name.Enter Tel.No.). It is actually supposed to print "Enter Name." then input the name, And then again print "Enter Tel.No.".
How can I fix the issue? I have to use parametrized constructor dynamically while creating an object.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>

using namespace std;

class myClass
{
     string  fullname,telephone;

public:
       myClass(int taskType = 2)
       {
          if(taskType==1)
          {
              add_record();                  
          }
          else if(taskType==2)
          {
              //view_records();
          }
          else if(taskType==3)
          {
              //delete_record();
          }else{
             // custom_error();
          }        
       }  
void add_record()
{
cout << "Enter Name.\n";
getline(cin, fullname);
cout << "Enter Tel. No.\n";
getline(cin, telephone);
}
   };

    main (){
          int myTask;
      cout << "Enter a Task-Type. \n"
           << "1 = Add Record,"
           << "2 = View Records,"
           << "3 = Delete a Record\n\n";
      cin >> myTask;
      myClass myObject(myTask);
           getch();
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably has nothing to do with your constructor, but rather with the mixing of cin >> and getline. Add a getline to a garbage variable after cin >> myTask and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `cin >> myTask` to read the first input. As you press enter to give the 1, selecting "Add Record", that 1 will be read from the buffer, but your newline will still be in the input buffer. Thus, the first `getline` will only read this off the buffer, producing an empty input for the line `getline(cin, fullname);`

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the first newline after the task type is not consumed by

```
cin >> myTask
```

so the `fullname` reading will only read an empty line and the "enter Tel.No" thing will be printed directly.

Insert a `getline` call after the `cin >> myTask` to fix this problem.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819082/stdgetline-on-stdcin).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, I added    getline(cin, myTask);    right after  cin >> myTask    but i got error :(....shall I change the data-type of      myTask    ? P.S. Fixed the problem by applying getline for a junk variable.