# For-Loop Skipping getline C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, getline

I'm having a problem where my for-loop skips over the getline function. If I replace it with **std::cin** then it works, so I think it's something related to what I inputted in getline.

Here's my code.

```
void setLocations(int amount) {
    locations = new std::string[amount];
    locations[0] = startingLocation;

    // starts at 1 because we want to skip first index. The amount is set at 2 by default, so the loop should iterate at least once.
    for (int x = 1; x < amount; x++)
        std::getline(std::cin, locations[x]);    
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819082/stdgetline-on-stdcin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you use 'std::cin>>someVar'  before  'setLocations' function call, which doesn't consume newline. To resolve, use this code segment before 'for' loop

```
std::cin.ignore(1, '\n');
```

Comment: I got an error where it says I cannot initialize a parameter of int_type when using the 

cin.ignore(1, "\n");

Comment: @Xari, sorry my mistake use '\n' not "\n".