# reuse char array and cin.getline

Tags: c++, char

I cant use the s1[40] for the second time or longer in the circle and it's always full,

and **cin.getline(s1,40)**
is ignored at later times

```
char s1[40], ans = 'y';
while (ans == 'y')
{       
system("cls");
cout << "\n Enter a sentence : ";
cin.getline(s1, 40);
fflush(stdin);

cout << "\n________________________________________\n\n Again?(y/n)";
cin >> ans;
fflush(stdin);
};
```

Comment: put debug logs and see where it is going wrong

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819082/stdgetline-on-stdcin

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> ans;` will actually not remove eol so next `getline` will read an empty line and `cin >> ans;` will read first symbol of line. You should make `ans` an array as well use `getline` twice:

```
for(;;)
{
    char s1[40]{};
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n Enter a sentence : ";
    cin.getline(s1, 40);
    fflush(stdin);
    if(cin.fail() or cin.bad())
    {
        cout << "fail" << endl;
        break;
    }
    cout << "\n________________________________________\n\n Again?(y/n)";
    char ans[2]{};
    cin.getline(ans, 2);
    fflush(stdin);
    if(cin.fail() or cin.bad())
    {
        cout << "fail" << endl;
        break;
    }
    if(0 != strcmp("y", ans))
    {
        break;
    }
}
```